# How can I track property changes of a project item through visual studio Add-In

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I'm developing a Visual Studio 2010 Add-In and I'm stuck at this moment. I would like to receive notification about property changes of specific project items. For example I need to know if a new Form (winform) was added into my project.

There are 2 possibilities how to add a form into the project in Visual Studio 2010:

1. You can simply Add a new Form item through the context menu. In this case the *ProjectItemAdded* event is thrown by the IDE. The problem is, that at that time the new form is recognized as *eFileTypeCppHeader* and not *eFileTypeCppForm*.
2. The second option is to change the FileType property of a Header file to "*C++ Form*" through the property tab. There is no event which notifies the Add-In about this property change.

So, how can my Add-In know the property of an ProjectItem was changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out how to bind to the project property changed event. It is necessary to implement the *IVsHierarchy* interface and then implement the *OnPropertyChanged* event.  It is also necessary to enumerate through the opened projects and bind to their property changes one by one. See the example bellow.

```
public ref class Hierarchy: public IVsHierarchyEvents
{
private:
    IVsHierarchy^ TargetHierarchy;
    unsigned int TargetHierarchyCookie;

public:
    Hierarchy(IVsHierarchy^ THierarchy)
    {
        TargetHierarchy = THierarchy;
        TargetHierarchy->AdviseHierarchyEvents(this, TargetHierarchyCookie);
    }

    virtual int OnPropertyChanged(unsigned int itemid, int propid, unsigned int flags)
    {
        // your code here
    }

    ...
};




public ref class Connect : public IDTExtensibility2, public IDTCommandTarget
{
private:
    List<Hierarchy^>^ Hierarchies;

    ...

public:
    virtual void OnConnection(...)
    {
        appObject = dynamic_cast<DTE2^>(Application);
        addInInstance = dynamic_cast<AddIn^>(AddInInst);

        ...

        // obtain the service provider
        OLE::Interop::IServiceProvider^ SProvider = safe_cast<OLE::Interop::IServiceProvider^>(appObject);
        Guid Sol_GuidService = (Guid)(SVsSolution::typeid)->GUID;
        Guid Sol_riid = (Guid)(SVsSolution::typeid)->GUID;
        IntPtr Sol_ppvObject;

        // obtain the solution object
        if (SProvider->QueryService(Sol_GuidService, Sol_riid, Sol_ppvObject)==VSConstants::S_OK && IntPtr::Zero!=Sol_ppvObject)
        {
            IVsSolution^ Sol = safe_cast<IVsSolution^>(Marshal::GetObjectForIUnknown(Sol_ppvObject));
            IEnumHierarchies^ EnumHierarchies = nullptr;
            Guid ProjectGUID = Guid("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}");

            // enumerate through the projects and bind the project changed events
            if (Sol->GetProjectEnum((unsigned int)(__VSENUMPROJFLAGS::EPF_MATCHTYPE | __VSENUMPROJFLAGS::EPF_ALLPROJECTS), ProjectGUID, EnumHierarchies)==VSConstants::S_OK && EnumHierarchies!=nullptr)
            {
                UInt32 pceltFetched;
                array<IVsHierarchy^>^ rgelt = gcnew array<IVsHierarchy^>(1){nullptr};
                for (EnumHierarchies->Reset(); EnumHierarchies->Next(1, rgelt, pceltFetched)==VSConstants::S_OK && pceltFetched==1; )
                {
                    Hierarchy^ NewHierarchy = gcnew Hierarchy(rgelt[0]);
                    Hierarchies->Add(NewHierarchy);                         
                }
            }
        }           
    }

    ...
};
```